# Flot Legend - Interactive

Tags: flot

Was wondering if there is a plug-in already available for FLOT chart legend to be interactive like in highcharts

Providing the example out here

http://jsfiddle.net/yohanrobert/T3Dpf/1/

However, in a turn of event I tried my hand on mouseover event through jquery

```
   $(".legendLabel").mouseover(function(){
          // Unhighlight all points
         console.log($(this))
         plot.unhighlight();

    // The X value to highlight
    var value = parseInt($(this).context.innerText.replace('Series ',''))-1;

    // Retrieve the data the plot is currently using
    var data = plot.getData();

    // Iterate over each series and all points
    for (var s=0; s<data.length; s++) {
        var series = data[s];
        if(s==value){
            for (var p=0; p<series.data.length; p++) {
                plot.highlight(s, p);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me achieve the interactivity like in the example?

Comment: I have already looked at something similar what I was expecting from this...
http://jsfiddle.net/AcuC7/148/
was wondering if there is an way to do this for all charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extended `togglePlot` function for different plot types (we save the original plot type in the `hidden` property):

```
togglePlot = function (seriesIdx) {
    var plotTypes = ['lines', 'points', 'bars'];
    var someData = somePlot.getData();
    var series = someData[seriesIdx];
    $.each(plotTypes, function (index, plotType) {
        if (series[plotType]) {
            if (series[plotType].show) {
                series[plotType].show = false;
                series[plotType].hidden = true;
            }
            else if (series[plotType].hidden) {
                series[plotType].show = true;
                series[plotType].hidden = false;
            }
        }
    });
    somePlot.setData(someData);
    somePlot.draw();
}
```

For highlighting a data series like in highcharts add a `highlightPlot` function like this (here only for line series):

```
highlightPlot = function (seriesIdx) {
    var someData = somePlot.getData();
    $.each(someData, function (index, series) {
        someData[index].lines.lineWidth = (index == seriesIdx ? 4 : 2);
    });
    somePlot.setData(someData);
    somePlot.draw();
}
```

I also changed the inline event handlers to jQuery event handling to make it cleaner:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function () {
        togglePlot($(this).data('index'));
        return false;
    },
    mouseover: function () {
        highlightPlot($(this).data('index'));
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        highlightPlot(-1);
    },
}, 'a.legend');
```

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AcuC7/321/) for the full example.

Comment: Raidri: Thank you for your response, however this works for Line chart. Will this work for pie or bar?

Comment: I was actually looking for something dynamically looking for chart type and enable or disable series on legend click irrespective of chart type

Comment: Ok, that was not really clear in your question (or from the example). For that you would need an extended version of your togglePlot function. I will update my code and fiddle in a few minutes.

Comment: Updated for flots original plot types: lines, points and bar. If you use pie plugin, just add "pie" to the plotTypes array.

Comment: The fiddle link is at the end of the answer ^^